# Kotlin – Add 'hashMapOf' to Array

Tags: kotlin

Coming from PHP it's beyond annoying to deal with all kind of array types in Kotlin/Java like `listOf` `mutableListof` `arrayOf` `mutableArrayOf` etc

I just want be able to add values (`hashMapOf`) to a damn `array`.

After initializing `array` (if it's even an array or what ever):

```
val bla = mutableListOf(hashMapOf<Long, Int>())
```

I tried those:

```
bla.add(5L to 7)
bla.add(5L, 7)
bla += 5L to 7
```

how to do this right??

What I basically want:

```
val bla = array()

bla.add(4L, 7)
bla.add(5L, 8)
bla.add(6L, 9)
```

and then:

```
Log.d("tag", "get long from second: " + bla[1].getTheLong) // 5L
Log.d("tag", "get int from second: " + bla[1].getTheInt) // 8
```

Comment: In your code you basically have a `List<HashMap<Long, Int>>` now. I don't think that's what you want. You probably either want to have a `HashMap<Long, Int>` or a `List<Pair<Long, Int>>`.

Comment: Please check the edit I added to the question

Comment: check my first code snippet. It creates an empty hashmap and afterwards adds values to it.

Comment: "Coming from PHP" - there's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, in your code, `bla` is a `List<HashMap<Long, Int>>`.

I guess you want to have a `HashMap<Long, Int>`, which would result in this:

```
val bla = mutableMapOf<Long, Int>()
bla.put(7, 2);    
print(bla.get(0))
```

or you want to have a `List<Pair<Long, Int>>`, which results in this:

```
val bla = mutableListOf<Pair<Long,Int>>()
bla.add(Pair(7, 2))     
print(bla.get(0))
```

The difference is, that for a map each key must be unique. The list of pairs allows you to add multiple pairs that are equal.

Comment: Ok bla.get(0) is showing me [(7, 2), (7, 2)] but how to specifically get the int and the long?

Comment: Do you use the hashmap or the list variant?

Comment: Oh nvm it actually works, for what ever reason Android Studio cached the old prints and printed them out instead of the new results, needed to clear cache and run again. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution:

```
fun main() {

    val bla = mutableListOf(hashMapOf<Long, Int>())
    
    bla[0][0] = 5
    bla[0][1] = 7
    
    println(bla)
}

// Result:  [ { 0=5, 1=7 } ]
```

Answer (score 0):

From you edit it becomes clear you want

```
val blah = mutableListOf<Pair<Long, Int>>()
blah.add(Pair(4L, 7))
blah.add(Pair(5L, 7)) // equivalent to blah.add(5L to 7)
```

and then

```
Log.d("tag", "get long from second: " + bla[1].first) // 5L
Log.d("tag", "get int from second: " + bla[1].second) // 8
```

Comment: bla[1].first is giving me the entire bla??

Comment: Your solution works too so I upvoted, there was a problem with android studio